# Combing two select statements in sql with different column

Tags: mysql

Can someone help me with this?.

I have two select statements.

The first output is this

```
|ID|NAME|
|01|John|
```

AND the second output is like this

```
|PID|DATE|
|323|2015-03-03|
|324|2015-03-04|
```

And I want the result to be

```
|ID|NAME|PID|DATE|
|01|John|323|2015-03-03|
|01|John|324|2015-03-04|
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a cross-join

```
select
t1.*,t2.* from table1 t1
cross join table2 t2
```